# Setting spark yarn client

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I would like to make spark yarn client ([link](https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-spark)). Does it need to install hadoop ? or is it ok to install only yarn? ( [by this
    link](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/master/Dockerfile))

Comment: Spark Standalone has its own scheduler in the above shared links belong to Docker are you planning to run Spark and Hadoop/Yarn on Docker?

Comment: Yes, not standalone mode, I would like to make yarn client mode with use multi node. since no enough resource machine, I tried to do this on docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Spark do not require Hadoop for running. Apache Spark is an independent project which can run on its own. If you want you can even run it without apache yarn.

Spark support 3 type of cluster manager which are mesos, yarn and standalone. if you do not have yarn installed then it can use mesos and standalone and by default it uses standalone when you do not mention any preference for cluster manager.Links which you have mentioned is fine to use but I think more better resources are available on google.